# jQuery issue: Cannot read property of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code seems to be working fine on JSfiddle, but once im placing it to the a webpage that has jquery already loaded in the DOM, i get this console error, as seen on the screenshot.

The iframe selector that I do target, exists.
Any ideas?

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
var stickyTop = $("iframe[id*='google_ads_iframe']").offset().top;
$(window).scroll(function() {
var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop();
if (stickyTop < windowTop && $(".adSlot.headBanner").height() - $(".sticky").height() > windowTop) {
  $("iframe[id*='google_ads_iframe']").css('position', 'fixed');
} else {
  $("iframe[id*='google_ads_iframe']").css('position', 'relative');
}
});
});
```

[image: error]

Comment: Don't post pictures of code, post the actual code, along with a [MCVE]

Comment: Have you tried using the ID selector `$('#google_ads_iframe')`?

Comment: I need to capture the attritube that matches all *google_ads_iframe* selectors. I have many of them, under different names.

Comment: Are these elements being dynamically added to the page? (i.e. do they actually exist when your script runs? My guess is that they don't.)

Comment: Yes they do @Nathan . I do load my JS just before closing body tag, whereas those are being loaded right after its opening.

Answer (score 1):

`$("iframe[id*='google_ads_iframe']")`
will return array. You need to iterate through each of them.

Something like this

```
$("iframe[id*='google_ads_iframe']").each(function(i, val){
  $(val).offset().top;
  ...
});
```

Comment: Changing code this way, made errors go away, but made it stop working on jsfiddle aswell.

Comment: as pointed out by someone you need to post your code to help us debug. Here is something i put together https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/435649/

Comment: Here is the solution https://jsfiddle.net/p87jmj61/453/. The alert will show you the offset().top value.

Comment: Seems a better one - thanks for it, however im not able to set the sticky pixels amount. When in 250px height ad, it scrolls for more than 50pixels (the height of the div class) and when in 90px height ad, it scrolls for more than 210px also.

Comment: It seems to be working as expected regarding the offset total from your fiddle, but if I add a css position of top:0px, its not sticking to the bottom for 50px, as expected, but for more. Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/p87jmj61/489/

I think that the problem is that is related to the green area, but I want to make it relation-free. It should work using the area in the blue field

Comment: @jeejee I think you will get more traction on your css problem if you create a separate question for that. This question dealt with undefined problem you were running into with jquery.